# Navigation Controller from Storyboard to XIB? Coding for table cells not working on Storyboard? Use XIB?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard, xib

I initially had a mostly-functioning app that I had some hang-ups on.  I was trying to use XIB files to do specific coding for things like Scrollers and Tables.  The issue came when I tried to navigate back from the XIB to the Storyboard it was being presented from.  I posted about my issue on another site and found out I was not navigating within my app correctly because I was not using a Navigation Controller.

I started over on the app and now I have my Navigation controller issues taken care of. The app looks much better. Now I have come to an issue that led me to all of this in the first place. I'm trying to do a few more complex pages in the app involving tables, scrolling, and map functionality.  It seems as though certain code that I try to do can only be executed properly when I build the view in a new XIB file. If I try the same code in an .h or .m file for a View Controller on my Storyboard and just apply the class to it, I will get errors I don't understand.  For some things, it seems to work fine.  Pushing views with buttons, and redirecting to YouTube/Safari all work just fine.  I know all about classes, defining actions and coding them in the .h and .m files, so I know the code is going to the right place.  If I try anything with tables or scrollers, it seems to only work within a XIB.

I'm trying to do a scrolling table view in one of my View Controllers on the storyboard. I've tried using a View Controller with a table view inside of it, as well as a straight-up Table View Controller. Neither of the methods I have tried worked properly. The basic template works fine, but the minute I try to do any coding with it I get shut out. I watched several YouTube tutorials, and both of the methods I have tried threw up errors and crashed the app on that View Controller.

I had similar problems creating a scroll view. This is what let me to make my views in XIBs originally, as it seems the code works just fine with that method. But then I run into the problem of navigating from the XIB to a Storyboard, which is the problem I started with. I cannot seem to embed a Navigation Controller in the XIB and have it work properly in relation to the storyboard, that throws up more problems (which is why I was making my own Back button in the original post).  I only tried it messing around, as I don't really know what I'm doing.  I'm understanding some of it, through tutorials online, but then these very specific problems pop up that I can't find an answer to.

Most of these tutorials involve one or two View Controllers, and they're simple tutorials. Are there just some things you can only do from XIBs? Table Views, UIScrollView, nothing but problems. Everything else I do works fine, mainly just pushing views and redirecting to Safari, but still. If I can do everything in a Storyboard View Controller that I can do in a XIB view, it would make it a lot easier, but that doesn't seem to be the case. Am I wrong?

I guess the short way of saying this, is

1) Can I execute the same code in a Storyboard View Controller as I can in a XIB?  Why do some things I try only seem to work if I have a separate XIB to design the view? (ex. UITableViewController UITableView)

2) Is it possible to work with XIBs and Storyboards seamlessly?  I had trouble using a Navigation Controller in the XIB while also using one on the Storyboard.  Is there a correct way to do this?

---

Sorry, I didn't have xCode up when I posted this so I was justing trying to be as specific as possible.  I will try to explain what I'm doing currently so I can cut down on the clutter.

Here is the code from my ArtViewController.m, which is assigned to my View Controller with a table view within it:

```
{

    NSArray *titleArray;
    NSArray *logoFileArray;

}

@end

@implementation ArtViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

titleArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Frauenthal Center for Performing Arts",@"Muskegon Museum of Art",@"L.C. Walker Arena","Howmet Playhouse", nil];
    logoFileArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"",@"",@"","", nil];
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView

{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

{
    return titleArray.count;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    ArtCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (!cell)
    {
        cell = [[ArtCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.firstLabel.text = [titleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[logoFileArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
}
```

And my ArtViewController.h has a property like this:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *artTableView;
```

Then I have my ArtCell.h (UITableViewCell) with this:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *myImageView;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *firstLabel;
```

Here is my ArtCell.m, but I don't think I changed anything:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    // Initialization code
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

When I run the app, it crashes at the ArtViewController and gives me an error here:

```
titleArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Frauenthal Center for Performing Arts",@"Muskegon Museum of Art",@"L.C. Walker Arena","Howmet Playhouse", nil];
```

The error is THREAD 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_gpflt).

Comment: Add a specific problem. What are you trying that doesn't work? What's in your storyboards or xibs? Nobody can help you otherwise.

Comment: Sorry about that, I fixed it up with a lot more detail and some code.  I'll make sure to do that next time.

Comment: You missed '@' in front of your last object

Comment: Holy snap.  Thanks!  That fixed it right up.  Now I feel a little silly.  I really appreciate it.  That was driving me nuts.

Answer (score 0):

You posted really long story, without providing any code samples that you have problems with. In short, then answers to your questions yes and yes.

Everything that you create/change in Storyboard or in XIB files you can also do directly from the code. It's not recommended way of course especially if you're planning to extended and support your application going forward. Some things are just easier to do in the Storyboards (like auto-layout constraints)

You also can mix and match Storyboard and XIB files. It's quite common to have main application layout and flow in the Storyboard and define individual complicated views or table cells in individual XIB files.

I would recommend for you to try and isolate your problems. If you think you're having issues with Table Views - create a sample project with one table view and simple data source. Make sure it works using Storyboard or direct code. Then see how you can apply your knowledge to the main project you're working on.

Comment: Sorry about the lack of detail.

Comment: I added a lot of code and more explanation of what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
titleArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Frauenthal Center for Performing Arts",@"Muskegon Museum of Art",@"L.C. Walker Arena","Howmet Playhouse", nil];
```

The last string in your array, isn't. You don't have an `@` at the start of `"Howmet Playhouse"`.

The first 95% of your question was irrelevant :)